# tcsh globbing with alias

Tags: shell, alias, tcsh, glob

How should one use globbing inside an alias in [tcsh](http://www.tcsh.org/Welcome)? For instance, say we want an alias which moves all files which begin with a given string to a specific folder:

`alias mv_to_trash 'mv !\:1* ~/trash'` does not move all files starting with `jk` to trash:

```
mv_to_trash jk
```

yields

`mv: No match.` But there are two files, `jk1` and `jk2`, which should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a safe approach.  Please don't rely on the alias itself to expand wildcards, as doing so will violate the principle of *least astonishment*.  What if an unaware user will call an alias which will do unexpected globbing?

Much, much better is to let the alias take an arbitrary number of arguments

```
alias mv_to_trash 'mv \!* ~/trash'
```

and to call it by providing an explicit wildcard, if desired:

```
mv_to_trash jk*
```

This is both safer and more precise.  It also offers a greater control and flexibility: you can use other pattern-matching operators, if you will, without changing the alias definition.

Comment: OK, astonished but happy to learn about the "principle of least astonishment"! It even makes sense. However, my real problem was a bit more complex and I thought an answer to my question would solve my problem. I would really like a command line alias which can take a bunch of files that begin with  given string, say "jk", and put them in a subdirectory of that name (i.e., "jk/") in the current directory. How can one do that in tcsh?

Comment: If you absolutely need, you can use a something like `alias mv_to_subdir 'mv \!:1?* \!:1'`.  Note that the globbing pattern must be `!:1?*` and not just `!:1*`, otherwise you would ask to move `jk` into `jk`.

Comment: Thanks, that works very well! The question mark is what I had missing - will go check what that means.